# Circuit elements classification

Tags: electric-circuits

I want to understand from theoretical point of view the *structure* of electric circuits. I don't mean Ohm's law or the Law of induction...
E.g. there are resistors $R$, capacities $C$, inductors $L$ and EMF $\mathcal E$ *and they are coefficients in the second order linear differential equation* for the charge on capacitor $q$

$$
L\ddot{q} + R\dot{q} + \frac{1}{C}q = \mathcal E
$$

Can other elements of circuits be understood likewise? Can one derive a classification of all possible elements?

Comment: What other components do you mean? If you're thinking about semiconductor components, it won't be so easy, since they are non-linear.

Comment: it's ok if it will be non-linear

Answer (score 1):

Some Examples of [Non-Linear elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_element)

[Diodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode) : 
   Intensity  $I = I_0 (e^{\frac{V}{V_T}}- 1) $, see examples of [circuit with diodes](https://6002x.mitx.mit.edu/wiki/view/CircuitswithNonlinearElements)

[Transistors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor): see for instance [Transistors NPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPN_transistor#NPN), section "Large-signal models", to see Intensity/Voltage relations

Comment: That's fine, but I want some how a reverse derivation.  

You say: there are resistors - they are described this way, diodes - they are described this way, etc. What I want is that you start from some initial statement like - there is second order ODE and its coefficients are resistance (realised in nature by resistors), thermal voltage (realised by diodes), etc.  

Is this possible at all?)

Comment: For each component, there is a  physical law : for a resistor, the current $I$ and the potential difference $V$ are related by the Ohm'l law: $V = R I$, where R is the resistance. There are other laws for the expression of the potential difference function of $q$ (resp $\ddot{q}$) for capacities (resp. inductors). So, when you have your series circuit, the difference potentials are additive, so you got an equation of the form $V_R +V_C + V_I = \mathcal E$. When you replace $V_R, V_C, V_I$ by their values, you get the second-order differential equation in $q, \dot q, \ddot q$

Comment: OK, but are these laws arbitrary. Now we have all those nonlinear elements with fancy dependencies $V(I)$, can there be invented more that are irreducible to $V_R$, $V_C$, ... or is your equation the most general we can get?

Comment: When you have a series circuit, if you have components $1,2....n$ with a source voltage $\mathcal E$, the general equation is $V_1 +V_2 +....+V_n = \mathcal E$. This equation is always true. Then, for each component, you have to express the expression of $V_i$ in function of $q, \dot q = i,\ddot q = \dot i$. This expression is not at all abitrary, it depends on the physical nature of the component.

Comment: Yes, that's fine :) assume now that $V_i = V_i(q, \dot{q}, \ddot{q})$. For *small enough* $q$, $\dot{q}$ and $\ddot{q}$ I can expand in series: $V \approx V_0 + \frac{1}{C}q + R\dot{q} + L\ddot{q}$, so I believe for small enough currents this second-order ODE is the most general one - any circuit element is reducible (approximately) to $R$, $C$ and $L$. Now what is the general possible equation then?

Comment: Why small enough? You don't need that to have a second-order linear differential equation (With a series circuit RLC, ) !!! You have $V_R = V_R(\dot q)$, $V_C = V_C(q)$, $V_L = V_L(\ddot q)$

Comment: By expanding in series I'm just trying to show what I wanna get. Ok, $V_C = V_C(q)$, but can I have an element with $V_C = \ln\left(1+\sin^2(q)\right)$? Don't think so. What's the general possible dependence of $V_C(q)$, of $V_R(\dot{q})$, of $V_L(\ddot{q})$? What's the most general possible equation then?

Comment: My remark was about a "standard" RLC series circuits only. For "big" values of $q, \dot q; \ddot q$, the basic laws for $V_R, V_C, V_L$ are no more true.. Even some kind of [capacitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance) have more complicated laws (see Frequency-dependent capacitors) For a diode, you may use a Taylor expansion : you have $V = V_0 \ln (1 + \frac{i}i_0{})$. So, if $i<<i_0$, then you may do a Taylor series around $i = 0$, because $ln(1 + \epsilon) = \epsilon - \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^2 + ...$. So, there are a lot of possible different laws, and it depends on the context.